# How to obtain full device name

Tags: go, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using the [bettercap gatt package](https://github.com/bettercap/gatt) on Ubuntu to do a LE scan of local bluetooth devices. For some devices (mostly Apple devices), I get a shortened device name, ie. 'iPhone' as opposed to 'Bobs iPhone8'.

I realize the Advertising packets have limited space (32 bytes) so sometimes the name is truncated but that doesn't seem to be what's happening here. Also, if the Advertising packet has the Connectable bit set, then I connect to the device and discover the services. When I do that, even the 'Device Name' under the 'Generic Access' service returns the short form of the name.

Is there a specific call or protocol request I need to make to obtain the full device name? Or is this some sort of Apple security thing?